# Node.js vercel/pkg express 'return 0 error' and fastify errors. Error: File or folder not included into executable during compilation stage

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, path, fastify

When trying to compile your node project into an executable and you are using express for routing it may lead to an error like the one shown below:

```sh
john@john:~/Tofa/Projects/Convert node project into .exe/Secondtest/express$ ./express
Error: File or directory '/**/express/views/index.html' was not included into executable at compilation stage. Please recompile adding it as asset or script.
at error_ENOENT (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:539:17)
at findNativeAddonForStat (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1201:32)
at statFromSnapshot (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1224:25)
at Object.stat (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1250:5)
at SendStream.sendFile (/snapshot/express/node_modules/send/index.js:721:6)
at SendStream.pipe (/snapshot/express/node_modules/send/index.js:595:8)
at sendfile (/snapshot/express/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1103:8)
at ServerResponse.sendFile (/snapshot/express/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:433:3)
at /snapshot/express/index.js:21:9
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/snapshot/express/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

The index.js code (app starting point) is as shown below:

```js
/*jshint strict:false */

(function() {
    'use strict';
    // this function is strict...
}());

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Server = require('http').Server;
const server = new Server(app);

server.listen(8080);

// __dirname is used here along with package.json.pkg.assets
// sepkg .e https://github.com/zeit/pkg#config and
// https://github.com/zeit/pkg#snapshot-filesystem
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});
```

What could be the possible cause of the error?
How do you solve it in `express` or `fastify`?

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Your project may have two kinds of assets:

- Local files: you want to use a file that is bundled by the pkg (must be available at build time).
  Here you can use relative paths like `.`, `..`, `__dirname`, `__filename`, etc.
- Remote file: you want to use a file that is not available at build time (downloaded later, uploaded by users, etc.).
  Here you must not use relative paths. Instead, you have to use `process.cwd()` or other functions that derive paths at runtime.

### express

When trying to compile your node project into an executable and you are using express for routing it may lead to an error like the one shown below:

```sh
john@john:~/Tofa/Projects/Convert node project into .exe/Secondtest/express$ ./express
Error: File or directory '/**/express/views/index.html' was not included into executable at compilation stage. Please recompile adding it as asset or script.
at error_ENOENT (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:539:17)
at findNativeAddonForStat (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1201:32)
at statFromSnapshot (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1224:25)
at Object.stat (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1250:5)
at SendStream.sendFile (/snapshot/express/node_modules/send/index.js:721:6)
at SendStream.pipe (/snapshot/express/node_modules/send/index.js:595:8)
at sendfile (/snapshot/express/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1103:8)
at ServerResponse.sendFile (/snapshot/express/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:433:3)
at /snapshot/express/index.js:21:9
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/snapshot/express/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

The error originates from pkg being unable to recognize the path pattern used in the express routing. So if your initial route looked like the one in this `index.js` file:

```js
/*jshint strict:false */

(function() {
    'use strict';
    // this function is strict...
}());

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Server = require('http').Server;
const server = new Server(app);

server.listen(8080);

// __dirname is used here along with package.json.pkg.assets
// sepkg .e https://github.com/zeit/pkg#config and
// https://github.com/zeit/pkg#snapshot-filesystem
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});
```

where `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');` pkg won't work.

> It is a bad programming practice to concat paths directly.

To solve the problem don't use `__dirname` directly, use `path.join` or create a new function to solve this issue as shown below:

```js
function getDirPath() {
  if (process.pkg) {
    return path.resolve(process.execPath + "/..");
  } else {
    return path.join(require.main ? require.main.path : process.cwd());
  }
}
```

and replace it in the code where `__dirname` is to obtain a code as shown below:

```js
/*jshint strict:false */

(function() {
    'use strict';
    // this function is strict...
}());

// Setting up our app requirements

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Server = require('http').Server;
const server = new Server(app);
const path = require('path');

// Setting up our port

server.listen(5000);

// Configuiring simple express routes
// getDir() function is used here along with package.json.pkg.assets

app.use('/', express.static(getDir() + '/views'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(getDir() + '/views/index.html');
});


// Using a function to set default app path
function getDir() {
    if (process.pkg) {
        return path.resolve(process.execPath + "/..");
    } else {
        return path.join(require.main ? require.main.path : process.cwd());
    }
}
```

> Don't forget to require `path` at the beginning of your code.

### fastify

If using fastify, you can use:

```js
const resolve = require('path').resolve 
const absolutePath = resolve('./')
```